# Excel offset function used for multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, charts

I am new to excel formulas and vba etc. thats why i have no idea how to solve this problem.

Problem:
I want to create a dynamic chart using the offset function. Basically i want to show in my chart
the last 7 entries from the newest entry and insert all the data from the columns in it.

The current code that i used is this:
Bereich.verschieben is german for offset btw.

```
=BEREICH.VERSCHIEBEN(Historie!$C$307:$C$312;0,0;1;Charts!$B$58-1)
```

I want something like:

```
=BEREICH.VERSCHIEBEN(Historie!$C$307:$C$312;**0:5**;0;1;Charts!$B$58-1)
```

to show the data in the whole range. And i would like to add the part where i only show the last 5 entries from the current filled cell. In the picture below for example, from Col L to Col H all the data should be shown.

[image: Used Data]

What i current got is this:

[image: Chart]

The Data in the chart is further on the back with the current date. Thats why the numbers dont match up exactly.

Comment: Try the following amendment to your formula:
`=BEREICH.VERSCHIEBEN(Historie!$C$307:$C$312;0;ANZAHL2($306:$306)-6;;5)`

which translates to
`=OFFSET(Historie!$C$307:$C$312,0,COUNTA($306:$306)-6,,5)`
in English.
This formula shifts the array by the number of cells that have a value in the row 306 minus 6, which shall serve as a short proxy for finding the 5th last column of the table.

Comment: @DattelKlauber Thank you now i am getting the data from the 5 columns into the chart, but the chart still doesnt look like how it should. The X Axis should have gotten the machines as seperate columns with the date to seperate them. But it doesnt look like it.

Comment: Better asked, how do i change the offset method to show the dates from row 306 minus 6 only in the x axis?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want each machine to be a column and the 5 last dates to be the rows of the dynamic array then? Try the following then:
`=LET(Data,Historie!$307:$312,Dates,Historie!$306:$306,TRANSPOSE(INDEX(Data,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Data)),TRANSPOSE({2;0;0;0;0;0}+MMULT({0,0,0,0,0;1,0,0,0,0;0,1,0,0,0;0,0,1,0,0;0,0,0,1,0;0,0,0,0,1},SEQUENCE(5,1,COUNTA(Dates)-5))))))` where I'll leave the translation to German Excel syntax to you

Comment: This could be made much simpler if you either allow the dynamic array to be created through 2 instead of just one formula (1 for the machine codes and 1 for the data), or if you can use the formula `VSTACK()`

Comment: In German Excel syntax the formula above translates to: 
`=LET(Data;Historie!$307:$312;Dates;Historie!$306:$306;MTRANS(INDEX(Data;SEQUENZ(ZEILEN(Data));MTRANS({2;0;0;0;0;0}+MMULT({0.0.0.0.0;1.0.0.0.0;0.1.0.0.0;0.0.1.0.0;0.0.0.1.0;0.0.0.0.1};SEQUENZ(5;1;ANZAHL2(Dates)-5))))))`

Comment: @DattelKlauber How would u do it in simpler using 2 formulas? Would like to understand whats done and that looks so complicated

Comment: I am getting a reference error when using that line. Didnt change anything in it and also checked the german/englisch formulas to be sure but still nope

Comment: The formula as written in English syntax works for me.
I'll write a proper answer below in a simpler way (which requires 3 formulas in total).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated a data table similar to yours (the exact length and values are not important for the formulas):

[image: data table example]

I understand that you want to create a dynamic array similar to the one shown here:

[image: result table example]

The one shown here has been created using 3 formulas in the highlighted cells.

There are 2 ways to write these formulas that immediately come to mind. a) using `INDEX()` functions or b) using `OFFSET()` functions.

**Starting with the** `INDEX()` **based formulas:**

1. the formula for the machines is `=TRANSPOSE(Historie!$B$307:$B$312)`
2. for the last 5 dates `=LET(Dates,Historie!$306:$306,INDEX(Dates,1,SEQUENCE(5,1,MATCH(MAX(Dates),Dates,0)-4)))`
3. and for the values you can then use `=LET(Data,Historie!$307:$312,Dates,Historie!$306:$306,INDEX(Data,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(C3#)),MATCH(B4#,Dates,0)))`
   where the direct cell references correspond to the arrays as shown in the screenshot further below.

**And the** `OFFSET()` **based formulas:**

1. the formula for the machines is the same `=TRANSPOSE(Historie!$B$307:$B$312)`
2. for the last 5 dates you can use `=LET(Dates,Historie!$306:$306,TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(Dates,0,MATCH(MAX(Dates),Dates,0)-5,1,5)))`
3. and for the values `=LET(Data,Historie!$307:$312,Dates,Historie!$306:$306,TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(Data,0,MATCH(MAX(Dates),Dates,0)-5,6,5)))`

Both alternatives generate the same table as shown here below:

[image: formula reference screenshot]

**Note:** In both alternatives, I hard wrote some numbers into the formulas that imply that you want to extract the values for exactly 5 dates and exactly 6 machines. If either one or both of those numbers shall be variable, adjustments have to be made accordingly.

> Edit 1: Avoiding `LET()` function

When the `LET()` function is not available for your purposes, the above formulas can be rewritten. I will leave out the 1st of the 3 formulas since it doesn't use `LET()`

`INDEX()` **based formulas:**

2. the dates formula is `=INDEX(Historie!$306:$306,1,SEQUENCE(5,1,MATCH(MAX(Historie!$306:$306),Historie!$306:$306,0)-4))`
3. the formula for the values is `=INDEX(Historie!$307:$312,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(C3#)),MATCH(B4#,Historie!$306:$306,0))`

`OFFSET()` **based formulas:**

2. the dates formula is `=TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(Historie!$306:$306,0,MATCH(MAX(Historie!$306:$306),Historie!$306:$306,0)-5,1,5))`
3. the formula for the values is `=TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(Historie!$307:$312,0,MATCH(MAX(Historie!$306:$306),Historie!$306:$306,0)-5,6,5))`

These adjusted formulas generate the exact same table as the LET-formulas above. See [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc2Az.png)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, but it looks like the problem is, that i dont have the LET Function, because the version is from 2016. And because i cant update it, i wont be able to use the LET Function. Is there an alternative for it?

Comment: the LET function simply allows you to declare variables that you can use in subsequent calculations within the LET function. You can avoid the LET function by replacing those variables by their own respective formulas. I can adjust the answer in 3-4h from now.

Comment: Also how did u enter them in the end into the chart? I cant enter more then 1 formula into it and let it fix there. Atleast i am not that knowledgeable about it. Still thank you very much for all the help till now.

Comment: I added the functions excl LET after *Edit 1* to the answer above. Regarding the graphs, I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for and whether you need them to be dynamic (in the sense of whether they have to allow for a variable number of dates and machines) or if there are always exactly 5 dates and exactly 6 machines. Does one of the two graphs in this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu1gm.png) illustrate it correctly?

Comment: A graph like the one in the second picture with Machines on the X Axis would be the one.  I am gonna try it without the Let function then

Comment: I have now tried every formula above but i am still in the dark on how to get a dynamic chart using them. Because can use neither Let nor Sequence, i have to use the offset formula that you used above. But then again, i its just not working for me and i have litteraly no idea where the problem lies.

Comment: Also i would like to create the offset chart in your screen using the date in the same format like in your very first screen with the blue background dates

Comment: Are you able to generate the table using the offset function? If not, are you getting an error or what is the problem?

Comment: First of all, if i use =Transpose(Historie!$B$307:$B$312) a few cells below the Data i am getting the #Value and not the machines in 307:312

Comment: But because i dont need the machines to be dynamic i can just add them as they are, hard coded. Then the same with the dates, i am not getting the last 5 dates into the array using the offset method.

Comment: a) Is there any other data to the right of your data table? Or does it end with the last date and the last values for the machines? b) Are the dates formatted as numbers or as text?

Comment: Try again with `=TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(Historie!$A$307:$A$312,0,MATCH(MAX(Historie!$306:$306),Historie!$306:$306,0)-5,6,5))`
 This is pretty much the same formula except for the addition of absolute column reference in the array of the `OFFSET` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249033/discussion-between-dattel-klauber-and-ardor).